# How to keep RecyclerView always above View in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Im using `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1` and with that version it should be possible to use `WRAP_CONTENT` on a `RecyclerView` height. I for now have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/message_list_row_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/message_list_message_divider"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/message_list_message_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/message_list_layout_message"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_list_layout_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_list_edittext_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/message_list_button_send"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/message_input"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/message_list_button_send"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_image_send"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/custom_button_send" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Preview in Android Studio is showing the correct layout with the `RecyclerView` above the dummy line View i inserted. I need this kind of layout because the `RelativeLayout` with the `EditText` inside can grow in height (if there are mor than 3 lines the `EditText` is growing in height and also the `RelativeLayout`).

When i install it on my Phone there is a problem. The `RecylcerView` is not above the view i defined. it is filling the complete height of the device. so the last row of my recylcerview is always behind the relative layout.

Why that? And how can i fix it? I need the RecyclerView to stay ALWAYS above the my divider and to shrink in height when relativelayout is growing in height.

**Edit** I want to provide some screenshots to show you the problem. The first Screenshot shows my Chat with the current layout:

[image: Current Layout on Start]

But there is missing one item because the scroll height is bigger than defined by the layout. The missing item you can see here after i scrolled down:

[image: Missing Item]

When i now (just to find the source of the problem) remove `alignParentTop` from the `RecyclerView` and set its height to 300dp, the change of the height gets correctly respected:

[image: Changed height]

But as you can see several items are missing now because they are hiding out of the field of view (yes... even when i programmatically scroll to bottom after initialization). To show that all elements are there:

[image: Missing items]

So the height gets correctly set... but the last elements arent showing up until i manually scroll down. programmatically scrolling does not have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the RelativeLayout with EditText inside it `layout_below="@+id/message_list_message_divider"`. And remove the `layout_above` on the divider

Comment: This cant work. It would cause a Circular dependencies error and even if i remove the `layout_above` from the recyclerview too... the result isnt correct. cause the divider now isnt showing up at all because it gets moved to the very bottom of the screen from the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem with placing the element you want ti have on top as last child of the parent layout or try putting `android:translationZ="1dp"` into the recyclerview.

Comment: First solution does not change anything and i cant use `translationZ` since it is a API 21 or higher attribute.

Comment: Ok. Override `public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){if(hasFocus) {myRelativeLayout.bringChildToFront (myRecyclerView); myRelativeLayout.requestLayout();}}`

Comment: im in a fragment. and it would not be enough to get the layout requested only on focus change. there are other things changing the content. The basic problem is that my relative layout rules are ignored. and ofcourse i dont want that.